# Payment failed but order is placed on wp site

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have integrated the payumoney plugin into woocommerce. The pay button redirects to payu money page. However, the order is placed even if the payment fails. How do i make it show that the payment has failed and order cannot be placed? How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: This is a support question for the developers of the payumoney plugin and is off-topic here. I suggest you contact the developers.

Comment: Sure, will contact their development team.